# where the $PATH is created in ubuntu (16.04) and how to change it

Tags: path, ubuntu-16.04

when checking my $PATH on ubuntu (16.04) 
I get a long list of directories, few of which even do not exist in my file 
system, and some of them I just don't need:

> > echo $PATH

.../usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

where they are created and how can I remove them?
I wnant to control the creation of the $PATH, rather than 
correct it later by the tricks described in 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/removing-a-directory-from-path

Answer (score 1):

Some typical places where $PATH can be set when starting up a bash shell on Ubuntu include:

- /etc/profile
- ~/.profile
- ~/.bashrc

where ~ represents your home directory.

Also look at any scripts called by those scripts.

There may be other things that get called when starting up a bash shell, depending on various conditions.  For details, take a look at the INVOCATION section from the command:

```
    $ man bash
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/141723) from askubuntu.com to edit the path either using a text editor or the command line.

Comment: thanks, but editing .bashrc or .profile is irrelevant to my question. I do add my paths and customize my .bashrc, but that was not my question..

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to your question today. The path you want to edit is in `/etc/environment`.